# How to upload text file to nodejs without a form

Tags: javascript

I am interested in finding a way to save simple data (table data) - from the browser to the node server without user interaction - my browser client html javascript application creates a table - and that table disappears whenever the browser is refreshed - so I would like to have the data saved to the server,  and after refresh have the browser javascript reference the table data and reconstruct the page table. (retrieving is not a problem I think.)  The problem is that everything I've seen relating to uploading to node server is related to forms.  That involves the user having to select a file and upload the data.  I'd like to bypass that.  Can anyone think of a way to do this?  Imagine a piece of text;

var mycontent = "Here is the text I would like to send to have saved.";

I would like to simply have a way to upload that to the node server. I've looked at the multer, express, express-fileupload - they're examples all appear to have forms - not desirable in my case.

Any pointer to packages would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `LocalStorage API` if you just want to prevent losing data when page refreshes.

The second variant could be saving data on `onunload` event

To use forms format take a look at `FormData`, you can build it programmatically without html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: I ended up using socket.io - I had it setup of to stream data from the browser for another purpose - so I just setup node to identify my table data separately and save that text to a file. Thanks for your input.